# toggle CSS auto expand height

Tags: jquery, css

I'd like to have the box shows in the middle of the page, I have two blocks, one on the left, and on the right, I used 'float' option align each edge, but I cannot get the the actual height (or auto-height) through the expand show/hide panel.
if I remove `float` option, it works fine, but I do need float, and also centralize the box. 
If someone could help? thanks alot

here is what I did,

**Markup**

```
<div id="box">
 <div class="selection">Some selection</div>
 <div class="open">Click ME</div>
 <div class="showpanel">This is content</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#box{
    border:2px solid #000;
    width:450px;
    min-height:300px;
    padding:10px 0;
    margin:0 auto;

}
.open {
    width:350px;
    height:50px;
    background:blue;
    margin:5px auto 0px auto;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:right;
    float:right;
}
.showpanel{
    width:350px;
    height:300px;
    margin:0 auto 10px auto;
    background:red;
    display:none;
    float:right;
}

.selection{
background:green;
width:100px;
height:140px;
float:left;

}
```

​
**JS**

```
$('.open').click(function() {

    $('.showpanel').slideToggle('slow');


});​
```

​

[Sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/PJDbb/)

Comment: Always include the relevant code along with fiddle demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear the `float`

```
<div id="box">
 <div class="selection">Some selection</div>
 <div class="open">Click ME</div>
 <div class="showpanel">This is content</div>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PJDbb/2)

Or use the `overflow` hack (keeping the same markup)

```
#box {
    border:2px solid #000;
    width:450px;
    min-height:300px;
    padding:10px 0;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;

}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PJDbb/3/)

Answer (score 4):

To make the outer div expand out as needed when slide toggling a floating child, adding `overflow: hidden` to your outer DIV (`#box`) should do.

Check the **demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/PJDbb/1/